# Module parse failed in angular

Tags: angular, webpack, loader

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (41:13)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

```
|signUp(data, Object);
| void {
>     console, : .warn(data),
|     this: .seller.userSignUp()
| };
```

Seller-auth html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/light.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Seller Sign-Up</h1>
    <form #sellerSignUp="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signUp(sellerSignUp.value)">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" ngModel name="Name" placeholder="Enter name">

        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" ngModel name="Email" placeholder="Enter email">

        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" ngModel name="Password" placeholder="Enter password">

        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Seller-auth ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from "./services.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-seller-auth',
  templateUrl: './seller-auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./seller-auth.component.css']
})
export class SellerAuthComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { private seller:ServicesService }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  signUp(data:Object):void{
    console.warn(data)
    this.seller.userSignUp();
  }

}
```

Service ts code:

```
userSignUp(){
    console.warn("service called");
    
  }
```

Trying to call a service to see wheather it is working or not. Actually i am creating an e-commerce website so i create a seller sign up form and that time it is working well and showing it's output in the console. but as soon i created a service and trying to call it for the same sign up button. it's showing this error. Tell me how can i resolve that?

Comment: Need some source code, won't be able to help just with an error. There is n number of possibilities.

Comment: Take a look Vimal. I have updated the body section code